# Dynamically built Navigation bar using angulars but not working properly

Tags: angularjs

I have build sidebar navigation menu from API JSON data. 
But after bind data to sidebar navigation menu it will showing all menu with collapsed state after click on some option in sidebar navigation menu then it is working properly.
but at initial stage it is collapsed.
also when i click on some option in some menu of sidebar it is not in collapsed state that menu is closed state but if i click on option from same menu then it is collapsed state

```
       <li ng-repeat="link in links" ui-sref-active="active" >                               
            <a href=""><i class="{{ link.ShortName }}"></i><span class="nav-label">{{ link.Name | translate }}</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                <li ng-repeat="subItem in link.ProgramList">
                    <a ui-sref="{{subItem.AccessibleName}}" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">{{ subItem.Name | translate  }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

this is API call

```
 $http.get('http://localhost:53396/api/Module/Get').success(function (data) {
    $scope.links = data;     

});
```

Comment: How are you toggling the collapsed state?

Comment: at initial state i.e after loading navbar using JSON that menus are not toggling when i click on that menus but when when i click on one of option in menu then they are toggling